# How do I publish a Greasemonkey script as a Firefox add-on?

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I recently have worked on a script in Greasemonkey and would like to publish it as an add-on for Firefox.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just post your script at <strike>[userscripts.org](http://userscripts.org/)</strike><sup>1</sup>  [OpenUserJS.org](https://openuserjs.org/) (Or one of the other userscripts.org replacements).
Trying to repackage it as an add-on is usually more trouble than it is worth.

---

If you really must, you can use [the Greasemonkey script compiler](https://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler.php) to turn your script into an "add-on", and then [submit that add-on to Mozilla, via the normal add-on process](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/developers/docs/policies/submission).

**Note that Wladimir's answer is better than the Greasemonkey script compiler.**

---

<sup>1</sup> [Userscripts.org is now long dead](http://www.ghacks.net/2014/05/09/userscripts-org-good-alternatives/).

Answer (score 10):

While you can "compile" a GreaseMonkey script (see Brock's answer), this solution isn't exactly well-supported. The more reliable option would be using the [Add-on SDK](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK) and [JPM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Tutorials/Getting_Started_%28jpm%29). Your `lib/main.js` file can be really simple ([`page-mod` module documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/page-mod)):

```js
var data = require("sdk/self").data;
var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*.example.com",
  contentScriptWhen: 'end',
  contentScriptFile: data.url("contentScript.js")
});
```

This is equivalent to the following GreaseMonkey script header:

```js
// @include http://example.com/*
// @include http://*.example.com/*
```

And then you add your GreaseMonkey script as `data/contentScript.js` (Add-on SDK will ignore the GreaseMonkey header, the info is specified elsewhere) and build the extension. In most cases it will just work - unless your GreaseMonkey script uses any special GreaseMonkey API of course, in which case you will need to find a replacement. [`unsafeWindow` is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/Guides/Content_Scripts/Interacting_with_page_scripts#Access_objects_defined_by_page_scripts) by the way (usual warnings apply).

Comment: What do you mean by "not exactely well-supported"? In the sense of "does not/rarely install" or "Bloated code"?

Comment: @RobW: I mean: "ancient solution that somebody hacked together years ago and didn't really update since". It is suboptimal in a number of ways, like requiring a browser restart for extension installation, but nobody is going to fix that.

Comment: I tried to edit this, but they didn't accept it. But this exact script doesn't work anymore. I had to modify it based on the Mozilla documentation. `var pageMod = require("sdk/page-mod");
var self = require("sdk/self");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
  contentScriptFile: [self.data.url("contentScript.js")]
});`

Comment: @trlkly: Right, SDK module resolution changed a while ago - I fixed that. The other changes are unnecessary, they might make sense depending on what you are doing but not necessarily.

Comment: Thanks for fixing it. But `@contentScriptWhen: 'end'` is still wrong. GreaseMonkey scripts by default start at DOMContentLoaded, so it should be `@contentScriptWhen: 'ready'`