# How do I create a Firefox addon from a Greasemonkey script?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, greasemonkey

I have a Greasemonkey script written in JavaScript, with a CSS component, and I'd like to publish them as a single Firefox addon. I've tried using the Addon Builder with the Addon SDK, but I haven't had any success. I've also tried the [User Script Compiler](https://arantius.com/misc/greasemonkey/script-compiler.php), to no avail. I'm just hoping someone could explain to me a simple way to package the .js file and the .css file as a Firefox addon, or how to user the Addon Builder to do this, since apparently what I've tried hasn't worked. Please, let me know if you need any more information from me, and thanks for your help!

EDIT: This is my main.js file in the Addon Builder.

```
 var data = require("self").data;
 var pageMod = require("page-mod");
 pageMod.PageMod({
   include: "[http://www.trello.com/board/*", "https://www.trello.com/board/*"],
   contentScriptWhen: 'end',
   contentScriptFile: data.url("scrumello_beta.js")
 });
```

Comment: Well what have you tried? and what errors are you getting?

Comment: I've tried including the script in the Addon Builder, which I'll edit my above post to include. I'm not getting any errors, per se, but the script isn't being called, I'm not sure what's happening. The script is a plugin for a certain set of pages that causes new elements to render on that page, and when I navigate to that page while running the addon, nothing is rendered.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I publish a Greasemonkey script as a Firefox add-on?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11667776/how-do-i-publish-a-greasemonkey-script-as-a-firefox-add-on)

Comment: Short answer is don't.  Just fold the CSS into the script and use `GM_addStyle()`.  Or post the file to Github (etc) and use `@resource`. ... Long answer, if you really insist on making an extension, see Wladimir Palant's answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: Our plan for this project is to make it an extension, since we want to deploy this throughout our company, and most people here either don't know how or won't like to install Greasemonkey, add the script to it, and download the CSS file. It's basically a necessity to publish this as an extension. Also, thanks for linking to that question, but I already found it. I read through it and tried the answers, which gave me the results I just explained in my previous comment.

Comment: Last I checked, his method worked, give his answer a reread.  I'll double-check, step-by-step maybe later today. Remember that the Greasemonkey API is NOT available using Wladimir's method.  Post or link to your complete script, in case there is some factor that stops it from compiling.

Comment: I've tried his method, and when I try to test the extension, I get the error "Wrong response from Addon Builder Helper" and the extension doesn't compile. I've updated my original question with my actual code in the Addon Builder.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your match pattern is wrong. If you take a look at the [documentation](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/1.8/packages/api-utils/match-pattern.html), you have to specify the protocol unless you are using a host-based pattern. The following will work:

```js
include: "http://www.trello.com/board/*",
```

If you want to include HTTPS connections as well then you should specify two patterns:

```js
include: ["http://www.trello.com/board/*", "https://www.trello.com/board/*"],
```

Other than that your `main.js` seems fine. The error message you get appears to be [bug 750138](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=750138) which is a bad interaction with the Add-on Builder Helper extension. Reinstalling the helper extension supposedly makes the issue go away.

Comment: Alright, I tried what you suggested. The error went away, but nothing happens still when I go to test my script on Trello. I've updated my question with the most recent main.js. Thanks for your help, already.

Comment: The fault is probably in `scrumello_beta.js`, post or link that file.  It ***probably*** has nothing to do with *"How do I create a Firefox addon from a Greasemonkey script?"*.

Answer (score -1):

I just wanted to let everyone know that I was able to resolve this question with Wladimir's help, and also a realization that my team and I made. I will not be posting my scrumello_beta.js file since it had nothing to do with the problem, and also since I cannot post company code. Our problem was how we were injecting our Javascript, which we resolved on our own. Thanks for all that tried to help me, I just wanted to give a bit of closure and let you all know that we're making progress now.